# Stored Procedure Order of Operations

Tags: stored-procedures, merge, sql-server-2008-r2, locking, blocking

I have a stored procedure which starts by creating a temp table, then it populates the temp table based on a query.

It then does a `Merge` statement, basically updating a physical table off of the temp table. Lastly it does an `Update` on the physical table. Pretty basic stuff.

It takes ~8 sec to run. My question is, at what point does it lock the physical table? Since the whole query is compiled prior to its run, is the physical table locked during the entire execution of the stored procedure, or does it wait until it gets to the statements that actually works with the physical table?

I'm not necessarily trying to resolve an issue, as much as make sure I don't cause one. We have other processes that need to be reworked to alleviate blocking, I don't want to create another.

Comment: Also, many database systems have different types of locks. It may be that a lock is placed that prevents any DDL changes being applied to the table but allows any other DML statements to make changes to the data within the table. Are you interested in any kind of locks or just specific one(s)?

Comment: It is a SQL 2008 R2 db.  I want to make sure the data in the table is accessible to end users as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, for SQL Server:

- a stored procedure is "compiled" (e.g. an execution plan is determined) before it's first usage (and that execution plan is cached in the *plan cache* until it's either tossed out due to space constraints, or due to a restart). At the time an execution plan is determined, **nothing** happens on the table level - no locks, nothing
- SQL Server will by default use row-level locks, e.g. a row is locked when it's read, inserted, updated or deleted - then and only then. So your procedure will place *shared locks* on the tables where it selects the data from to insert those rows into the temp table, it will put **exclusive locks** on the rows being inserted into the temp table (for the duration of the operation / transaction), and the `MERGE` will also place locks as and when needed

Most locks (not the *shared* locks, typically) in SQL Server are by default held until the end of the transaction. Unless you specifically handle transactions explicitly, each operation (`MERGE`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT`) runs inside its own *implicit* transaction, so any locks held will be released at the end of that transaction (e.g. that statement).

There are lots more aspects to locks - one could write entire **books** to cover all the details - but does this help you understand locking in SQL Server at least a little bit ?